# nodeJS + MonogoDB - TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

i started to work with nodeJS and mongoDB and just n the start, after i connect to the db, i get this error.
i read every article on the internet and still dont work...
i open aone connection over mongoDB and try to insert data, the code:

```
var insertUserMovieRating = function(successCallback, errCallback, movieName, rating) {
    var url = config.db.databaseType + '://' + config.user + ':' + config.password + '@' + config.db.server + ':' + config.db.port + '/' + config.db.databaseName;
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (err) {
            errCallback(err)
        }
        if (db != null) {
            console.log("insert");
            var collection = db.collection(config.db.databaseName);
            collection.update({
                title: movieName
            }, {
                '$push': {
                    'rating': rating
                }
            }, {
                upsert: true
            }, function(err, res) {
                if (err) errCallback(err);
                successCallback("ok");
                // db.close();
            });
        }
    });
};
```

how i solve this problem? i seriousthat i sitting on that 5 hours and still dont solve this, i really appreciate every help that i will get here, thanks!

SOLVED: the solution was to really write the value of connection to URL var and not by other variable.
Thanks to all people who helped me!

Comment: In what line does the error occur?

Comment: here: var collection = db.collection(config.db.databaseName);

Answer (score 2):

I think you have an issue with db.collection(config.db.databaseName). Your database is not the same as the collections it holds. It looks like you aren't actually getting a handle on the proper collection.

Maybe try something like

```
var collection = db.movies;  // or whatever the name of your collection is
```

For issues like these I'd always suggest opening up the MongoDB shell and figuring out the syntax and getting it to work in there. Once you have the solution you can just paste it into your Node.js code.

Comment: tried, and now get  TypeError: Cannot read property 'movies' of null. i did it on local mngoDB first and then go to mlab , there the troubles begins

Comment: I forgot to tell, when I print the var db I get null, if it's tell something

Comment: Where do you print it?

Comment: Line before if (db!=null)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed to passed your **collection name** and you need to error handling if collection is not defined with updating record in a collection.

```
        var insertUserMovieRating = function(successCallback, errCallback, movieName, rating) {
            var url = config.db.databaseType + '://' + config.user + ':' + config.password + '@' + config.db.server + ':' + config.db.port + '/' + config.db.databaseName;

            //url = 'mongodb://admin:password@localhost:27017/db'
            //make sure your url look like as above
            MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
                if (err) {
                    errCallback(err)
                }
                if (db) {
                    console.log("insert");
                    var collectionName = 'movies'; // or whatever the name of your collection name , its similar like your table name in SQL
                    var collection = db.collection(collectionName);
                    if(!collection){
                      errCallback('Collection is not defined in database')
                    }
                    collection.update({
                        title: movieName
                    }, {
                        '$push': {
                            'rating': rating
                        }
                    }, {
                        upsert: true
                    }, function(err, res) {
                        if (err) errCallback(err);
                        successCallback("ok");
                        // db.close();
                    });
                }
            });
        };
```

Please check documentation post to [here](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html) and [here](http://fredrik.anderzon.se/2017/01/17/setting-up-a-free-mongodb-database-on-mlab-and-connecting-to-it-with-node-js/).

Hope this will help you !!

Comment: Thanks but the problem is that db is null and what you offer not happening because db is null

Comment: Have you check generated URL or can you please add to here

Comment: sure, this is the url with values:     mongodb://user:password@ds145193.mlab.com:45193/movies

Comment: http://fredrik.anderzon.se/2017/01/17/setting-up-a-free-mongodb-database-on-mlab-and-connecting-to-it-with-node-js/

Comment: Is this user get authorize with database

Comment: i think so, i dont get anything abut that so

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: i didnt get error about user auth so i dont think is the problen. how i check the auth?

Comment: Have you used var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient; or anything else

Comment: of course, without it there will be a lot of errors

Comment: test connection on mlab using mongo ds149373.mlab.com:49373/jwtsample -u <dbuser> -p <dbpassword>

Comment: output:Error: 18 { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth failed", code: 18, codeName: "AuthenticationFailed" } at src/mongo/shell/db.js:228

Comment: The issue is because you are using mongolab.com username and password, instead of the database username and password.

Comment: but i created user and password of db, add database user and then use the user and password that i gave

Comment: i updated the version of mongodb on bash and i success login, i read that in >3.0 append the auth stage so i update in linux because mlab use 3.4.7 version. the problem is in node. the driver is in version of 2.2 and i think is not compitable with mlab,what to do? i cant find driver version to node in >3.0